# App has stopped when try to implement RecyclerView in My HomeFragment

Tags: java, android

I am following a tutorial & I try to add RecyclerView into it by adding adapter and show this in my HomeFragment but my app unfortunately get stopped when i run the project on a emulator.

I have my HomeFragment, my adapter, my model

My HomeFragment.java

```
package com.medum.medum.view.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.medum.medum.R;
import com.medum.medum.adapter.CardAdapterRecyclerView;
import com.medum.medum.model.Picture;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    showtoolbar("Inicio",false,view);
    RecyclerView cardsRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardrecycler);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    cardsRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    CardAdapterRecyclerView cardAdapterRecyclerView = new CardAdapterRecyclerView(buildPict(),R.layout.cardview_picture,getActivity());
    cardsRecycler.setAdapter(cardAdapterRecyclerView);
    return view;
}

public ArrayList<Picture> buildPict(){
    ArrayList<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<>();
    pictures.add(new Picture("http://www.construyehogar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Idea-fachada-casa-dos-pisos-moderna-coralhomes.com_.au-.jpg","Casa en venta", 200000, "4 recamaras", "5"));
    pictures.add(new Picture("http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/casa/casa-06.jpg","Casa en renta", 5000, "2 recamaras", "6"));
    pictures.add(new Picture("http://www.terrazasdelpacifico.mx/images/departamentos_en_Tijuana_Lunada_img1.jpg","Departamento en renta", 3000, "2 recamaras", "6"));
    return pictures;
}

public void showtoolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton,View view){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
}

}
```

My Adapter - CardAdapterRecyclerView.java

```
package com.medum.medum.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.medum.medum.R;
import com.medum.medum.model.Picture;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CardAdapterRecyclerView  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapterRecyclerView.CardViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<Picture> pictures;
private int resource;
private Activity activity;

public CardAdapterRecyclerView(ArrayList<Picture> pictures, int resource, Activity activity) {
    this.pictures = pictures;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resource,parent,false);

    return new CardViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picture picture = pictures.get(position);
    holder.titlecard.setText(picture.getTitlecard());
    holder.pricecard.setText(picture.getPricecard());
    holder.descriptioncard.setText(picture.getDescriptioncard());
    holder.timecard.setText(picture.getTimecard());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pictures.size();
}

public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private CardView pictureCard;
    private TextView titlecard;
    private TextView pricecard;
    private TextView descriptioncard;
    private TextView timecard;
    public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        pictureCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picturecard);
        titlecard = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardtitle);
        pricecard = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        descriptioncard = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        timecard = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timecard);
    }
}
}
```

My model - Picture.java

```
package com.medum.medum.model;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Picture {
private String picture;
private String titlecard;
private int pricecard = 0;
private String descriptioncard;
private String timecard = "0";

public Picture(String picture, String titlecard, int pricecard, String descriptioncard, String timecard) {
    this.picture = picture;
    this.titlecard = titlecard;
    this.pricecard = pricecard;
    this.descriptioncard = descriptioncard;
    this.timecard = timecard;
}

public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

public String getTitlecard() {
    return titlecard;
}

public void setTitlecard(String titlecard) {
    this.titlecard = titlecard;
}

public int getPricecard() {
    return pricecard;
}

public void setPricecard(int pricecard) {
    this.pricecard = pricecard;
}

public String getDescriptioncard() {
    return descriptioncard;
}

public void setDescriptioncard(String descriptioncard) {
    this.descriptioncard = descriptioncard;
}

public String getTimecard() {
    return timecard;
}

public void setTimecard(String timecard) {
    this.timecard = timecard;
}
}
```

Adapter xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/picturecard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/prueba"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:background="#8c0085B2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cardtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Casa en venta"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="$145,000.000 MXN"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hace"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timecard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4 dias"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/fav_selected"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messageuser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/chat" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat

```
08-04 12:58:39.870 9223-9223/com.medum.medum E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.medum.medum, PID: 9223
                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.CardView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
                                                               at com.medum.medum.adapter.CardAdapterRecyclerView$CardViewHolder.<init>(CardAdapterRecyclerView.java:64)
                                                               at com.medum.medum.adapter.CardAdapterRecyclerView.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapterRecyclerView.java:36)
                                                               at com.medum.medum.adapter.CardAdapterRecyclerView.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapterRecyclerView.java:20)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6411)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5597)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3625)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3354)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3886)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:868)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
08-04 12:58:39.871 9223-9223/com.medum.medum E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:736)
                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2480)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2199)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1385)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6722)
                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:886)
                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:698)
                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:633)
                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:872)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the content of the exception instead of attaching a picture.

Comment: Please post the xml of adapter as well

Comment: Already did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting Imageview and not cardview try change this:

```
 private CardView pictureCard;

pictureCard = (CardView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picturecard);
```

**Or**:

you added wrong id.And if is that just change this:

```
pictureCard = (ImageView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverImageView);
```

Comment: wath you do ghange variable to cardview? Or change id ? @ArturoPerez

Comment: First Variable and same thing, later the id and same

Comment: You aren't doing anithing with cardview what happens if you remove **pictureCard** from adapter code?

Comment: when i removed from the code nothing, but the app still crushing

Comment: The logcat is the same?

Answer (score 2):

You are casting wrong view. Do this :

```
    private CardView pictureCard;

        pictureCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picturecard);
```

in your ViewHolder.

Also, this import:

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

in model class doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I see that you're not using the CardView or ImageView anywhere in the adapter. Just remove the declaration and assignment. See if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your view with id `picturecard` represents a `Cardview`, but you are treating it as an `ImageView`. Hence the `ClassCastException`.

I would suggest replacing these lines
`private ImageView pictureCard;` and    `pictureCard = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.picturecard);`

with

`private CardView pictureCard;`  and  `pictureCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picturecard);`

respectively

Comment: Can you post the updated code and stacktrace after making the changes?

Comment: Either the stacktrace is incorrect or your phone is not have the app with latest updated code. Please clean the project and run again.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your full XML code then I'm not find any tag of ending cardview. So, please close your cardview with

```
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```